# ListView not displaying right

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

So i`m coding this custom listView Adapter. The adapter AXML looks like this: [image]

The problem is that when i compile and run in emulator, the ListView item turns into this :
[image]

Can anyone help me figure out what is happening? Maybe help me fix it?. If you need any code let me know.

UPDATE: AXML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
                android:text="ABC 232"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/shopName"
                android:textColor="#3c3c3c"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:weightSum="1">
           <TextView
                    android:text="~800m away"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/distance"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
                    android:textColor="#3c3c3c"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="Total: 12.45 RON"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/total"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="22.0dp"
                android:textColor="#3c3c3c"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please clearly describe what is the exact problem? And please share your code so people can find where the problem. Stackoverflow isn't a place people magically find and fix your code.

Comment: should i put the whole axml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change all the text views width and height attribute to `wrap_content`. Specially for text view for `shopName`.

You can also remove `linearLayout1, linearLayout3 and linearLayout4`. Since they added noting important to your view.

Comment: Why didn't you change the width and height attribute of each TextView ? I hope changing the height attribute of shopName text view will solve your issue.

Comment: skipped one :) sorry :)

Comment: Remove `layout_weight` of `linearLayout2 `. You can also remove `linearLayout5` :)

Comment: this one did it :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to encapsulate each TextView in a LinearLayout. If you desire padding around the font, the TextView has padding attributes that will achieve the same effect in a cleaner manner.

If you clean up the code in this way, the issue with views not appearing may appear clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be much simpler, use relative layout and align all three text one another. 
Steps to design:
1) Take Parent Relative layout and make it centre vertical and horizontal
2) Place text1 and make align top of parent and give margin or padding from left
3) Place text2 below of text1 and give padding or margin from top.
4) Place text3 toRight of text1 or text2 or make make it centre vertical and horizontal of parent or you give margin left. it is your choice which once you choose.
Let me if you want more help. :)GlbMP